# index of closest a number in array, closest to x, that cannot be larger than x

Tags: c#, arrays, search

How can I write a function that accepts an array of integers and an integer x and returns the index of the integer in the array that is closest to x argument without being larger than x.  If all are above x, the function will return negative one.  Assuming two or more numbers cannot be the same in array.

Comment: what if there are multiple results?

Comment: There will not be multiple solutions. It says to return the closest one, and assumes there are no duplicates in the array.

Comment: there wont be. all the numbers in array are different

Comment: Depends on how performance critical the function is. I might just sort it and then do a binary search. I would stay away from linq though - in my experience it has *horrible* performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming that are numbers are unique you could use

```
public static int GetClosestIndex(int[] arr, int value)
{
    var result = arr.Where(x => x < value).OrderByDescending(x => x);
    return result.Any() ? Array.IndexOf(arr, result.FirstOrDefault()) : -1;
}
```

**Update:**  (for Zastai)

here is a better performing approach

```
public static int GetClosestIndex(int[] arr, int value)
{
    int result = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] < value)
        {
            if (result == -1 || arr[i] > arr[result])
            {
                result = i;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: While functionally correct and fairly elegant in code, this is almost certainly going to perform quite badly.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with

```
public static class StackOverflow {

public static int IndexOfValueClosestTo<T>(this IList<T> list, T x) where T : IComparable<T> {
  var closestValue = default(T);
  var closestIndex = -1;
  var idx = -1;
  foreach (var v in list) {
    ++idx;
    if (v.CompareTo(x) < 0 && (closestIndex == -1 || closestValue.CompareTo(v) < 0)) {
      closestIndex = idx;
      closestValue = v;
    }
  }
  return closestIndex;
}

}
```

It is still very readable, works on arrays, lists, ... and handles integers, doubles, ...
It's also an extension method, so you can use both `StackOverflow.IndexOfValueClosestTo(mylist, myvalue)` and `mylist.IndexOfValueClosestTo(myvalue)`.

Some basic benchmarks in LINQPad with an array of a million elements also show this to be 30 times faster than the LINQ-based answer (with 100 iterations this takes ~1.05s where the LINQ version takes ~37s).

For the absolute best performance, however, use a version specialized to int arrays:

```
public static int IndexOfValueClosestTo(this int[] list, int x) {
  var closestValue = 0;
  var closestIndex = -1;
  var idx = -1;
  foreach (var v in list) {
    ++idx;
    if (v < x && (closestIndex == -1 || closestValue < v)) {
      closestIndex = idx;
      closestValue = v;
    }
  }
  return closestIndex;
}
```

That runs the 100 iterations in ~0.33s, so it's about 3 times as fast as the generic version above. Note that you can define both as overloads, so you still have a working implementation for, say, a list of doubles.